# Prove $0<a_k\in \mathbb R$ and $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n a_k =1$, then $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+a_k) \ge 2^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, products

Prove:$$0<a_k\in \mathbb R\quad and\quad\prod_{k=1}^n a_k =1,\quad then\quad \prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k) \ge 2^n$$

(*) I guess that the minimum of $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)$ happens when all $a_k$'s are $1$, but can't prove it. Thanks.

Comment: By [Hölder’s inequality](https://hcmop.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/holders-inequality/) $$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k) \ge \left(\left(\sqrt[n]{1}\right)^n+\prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt[n]{a_k}\right)^n=2^n$$

Comment: @user236182 Nice find.  One more tool in my tool box...

Comment: $$ (1+a_k)\geq 2\sqrt{a_k} $$ is enough.

Comment: See also [What is the minimum value of $(1 + a_1)(1 + a_2). . .(1 + a_n)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/547505) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/547505). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20(1%2Ba_k)%20%5Cge%202%5En%24&p=1).

Comment: Follows also from [Prove $(x+r_1) \cdots (x+r_n) \geq (x+(r_1 \cdots r_n)^{1/n})^{n}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078267/prove-xr-1-cdots-xr-n-geq-xr-1-cdots-r-n1-nn)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is simple $AM-GM$, we have
$$1+a_1\geq 2\sqrt{a_1}$$
$$1+a_2\geq 2\sqrt{a_2}$$
..........................
$$1+a_n\geq 2\sqrt{a_n}$$
multiplying all together we get
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n} 1+a_k\geq 2^n\sqrt{a_1a_2a_3...a_n}=2^n$$

Comment: Equality holds if and only if $\sqrt{a_k}=1$, i.e. $a_k=1$ for all $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.